# Is it possible to choose pull request templates like issue in github

Tags: github, pull-request

I have made `ISSUE_TEMPLATE` and `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE` in the `.github` folder and made custom templates for each folder.

In GitHub when I create an Issue, GitHub asks me which issue templates want but not for PR, I need to use the URL parameter.

Is there any way to choose pr templates before writing PR?

Comment: I am also looking for something similar, have you had any luck Chris? 
I see there is a Chrome extension for it, so I think it seems that perhaps it has not been implemented on GitHub yet?